# PHP How can I change array to string with formula math modulus?

Tags: php

I calculated modulo mathematics with the formula: 3 * n mod 26

by encrypting the array [n] A-Z to the conversion of numbers, the results of the numbers are obtained from the results of a predetermined array, then the calculated results are converted back into a string.

Example: MY NAME IS CARL > KU NAKM YC GAZH

K = 10, U = 20, N = 13, A = 0, K = 10, M = 12

Y = 24, C = 2, G = 6, A = 0, Z = 25, H = 7

I have managed to convert numbers into strings and get a result: KUANAKMAYCAGAZH

What I want to ask is how to delete 'A' by replacing spaces, so the result is: 'KU NAKM YC GAZH' not 'KUANAKMAYCAGAZH'

Sorry, for my bad English.

Below is my script:

```
<?php
$text = 'MY NAME IS CARL';
$str = '';

$key = array(
"A" => 0, "B" => 1,"C" => 2, "D" => 3,"E" => 4,"F" => 5,
"G" => 6, "H" => 7, "I" => 8, "J" => 9, "K" => 10,
"L" => 11, "M" => 12, "N" => 13, "O" => 14,
"P" => 15, "Q" => 16, "R" => 17, "S" => 18,"T" => 19,
"U" => 20, "V" => 21, "W" => 22, "X" => 23,
"Y" => 24, "Z" => 25
);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    $number = (3*$key[strtoupper($text[$i])])%26; // math caesar cipher 3 * n modulo 26
    $str .= array_search($number, $key);
}
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array_search` function to find the letter that corresponds to a number in your `$key` array. For example, `array_search(21, $key)` will return 'V'.

```
<?php
$text = 'HELLO';
$str = '';

$key = array(
"A" => 0, "B" => 1,"C" => 2, "D" => 3,"E" => 4,"F" => 5,
"G" => 6, "H" => 7, "I" => 8, "J" => 9, "K" => 10,
"L" => 11, "M" => 12, "N" => 13, "O" => 14,
"P" => 15, "Q" => 16, "R" => 17, "S" => 18,"T" => 19,
"U" => 20, "V" => 21, "W" => 22, "X" => 23,
"Y" => 24, "Z" => 25
);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
    $number = (3*$key[strtoupper($text[$i])])%26;
    $str .= array_search($number, $key);
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: when I try array_search to all if else, if ($ str == 21) {$ str. = array_search (21, $ key); }
I got the result: 21V12V7V7V16V
I want to get a result: VMHHQ
according to the formula script I wrote

Comment: Get rid of that if-else, and remove the line of code that adds the number 21 to `$str`. The for-loop in the answer has all you need.

Comment: I'm still confused, can you give an example? please, i'm a beginner in php

Comment: see udpate - I've added the rest of your code to the answer to make a complete example.

Comment: thank you. How to add a space? Example text: 'HELLO GUYS' to 'VMHHQ ASIUC'

Comment: If `$text[$i]` is space, add a space to $str